# Como alterar a versão do aplicativo em tempo de execução no C#

Tags: c#, versionamento

Preciso alterar a versão do aplicativo de 1.0.0.0 para 1.1.0.0 em tempo de execução, como posso fazer já que a propriedade ProductVersion é apenas get;

Comment: Acredito não ser possível. Pode explicar o por que quer mudar a versão em `runtime`?

Comment: Como você já disse, não tem como alterá-la em tempo de execução: `public static string ProductVersion { get; }`.

Comment: Não pode ser { get; set; } ?

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que em tempo de execução não seja a maneira ideal para isso.

O modo ideal para se atualizar esse id de versão, seria durante seu processo de Integração Continua, por exemplo, eu utilizo o VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) para meu cenário de DevOps, e realizo justamente a alteração que você está necessitando.

Durante meu processo de build automatizada, eu executo um script powershell (ou mesmo uma task do vsts) que acessa o arquivo assemblyinfo.cs (no caso do c# claro), e atualiza esse ID de versão, de acordo com o ID da build, para que caso necessário eu consiga rastrear que a versão 1.0.0.10293 foi gerado pela build com mesmo ID.